# Regular expressions in CSV database export

Tags: regex

I'm currently exporting and modifying my database from 2011 to use physical paths to my files. I'm trying to use search with regular expressions (I'm editing the CSV export with Notepad++), however, I have a problem with this because it doesn't find what I'm trying to search for. This is a part of my database:

```
"1","blahblah","description","68 KB","2011-02-12 17:19:17","0000-00-00 00:00:00","2011-02-12_www_website_pl_filename.rar","x","x","1720","59","3612","1"
"2","blahblahb","description","146.25 KB","2011-02-13 00:13:06","0000-00-00 00:00:00","2011-04-19_www_website_pl_something.rar","x","x","2201","59","3613","1"
```

What I'd like to find is this part:

```
"2011-04-19_www_website_pl_filename.rar"
```

and replace it with something like this this:

```
"/home/public_html/website/files/2011-04-19_www_website_pl_filename.rar"
```

So I'm trying to find this as a regular expression:

```
"[2011].*[_www_website_pl_].*"
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work - this expression finds almost all the lines. What's wrong with it? What should I write in the "Replace with" window so it only replaces the beginning of the path?

Comment: `[2011]` and `[_www_website_pl_]` suggest you should start by reading a regex tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?<=")(2011[^"]*?_www_website_pl_.*?)(?=")
```

And replace with

```
/home/public_html/website/files/\1
```

Comment: Thank you, it matches what was needed. However, the replacing part doesn't work. It just replaces it with the /home/public_html/website/files/ and doesn't copy the rest. As I assume, the \0 is what was matched - is that correct? I tried replacing it with just the \0 (or $0 or $1 if that matters) and in all cases it replaces it with a blank space. Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but it's my first time with regex.